# How to set a default key using the a key from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Consider a csv:

```
id   name    age
1    x       12
2    y       13
3    z       14
```

This is the code:

```
fnolcsvload = csv.DictReader(open('/Users/swaghccc/Desktop/CCCTestWithDataWithoutAccidentDescriptionCopy2.csv', 'rU'))
list_ = []
for rows in fnolcsvload:
    list_.append(rows)
```

Now I have a list of dictionaries.
I would like to know how to create a dictionary with one single key for multiple values.
For example, instead of:

```
list_ = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'x', 'age': '12'}...]
```

I would like to have a dictionary with a primary key, haveing all the rows in a csv as the values associated to that key. In other words a sample key-value pair would be:

```
{'id': {'id': '1', 'name': 'x', 'age': '12'},
 'id': {'id': '2', 'name':'y', 'age': '13'},
 'id': {'id': '3', 'name': 'z', 'age': '14'} }
```

Comment: why all other rows should be ignored?

Comment: `list_.append({'id':row})`?

Comment: how would the second row look like? Extend your desired result a bit.

Comment: I don't want the other rows ignored, that's an example of one row.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't want the end result to be a list but a dictionary as shown in the edited version of my question.

Comment: @TheTank that dictionary only maintains the last value for the `'id'` key...

Answer (score 0):

In short: you cannot do exactly that. A `dict` is a map of *unique* keys to values.

Good news: you can have a dict of *lists* very easily, each list storing multiple values when needed.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(list)  # Auto-creates a list for every accessed key.
>>> data['people'].append('Joe')
>>> data['people'].append('Jane')  # Same key.
>>> data['animals'].append('cat')
>>> data['animals'].append('dog')
>>> data["people"]
['Joe', 'Jane']
>>> data["animals"]
['cat', 'dog']
>>> data["something we never touched"]
[]
>>> _
```

Hope this helps.